# Width issues using HTML select within a DIV using IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Here is an example I have put on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7sYq/)

```
<div style='width:30px;border:solid 1px'>
  <select style='width:100%'>
    <option>This is my first option</option>
    <option>option</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div style='width:300px;border:solid 1px'>
  <select style='width:100%'>
    <option>This is my first option</option>
    <option>option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

In every browsers (FF,Chrome,Safari,IE9,IE9 in IE8 mode) other than IE 7/8, the options of the first combo are fully visible. IE8 is limiting the width of the options to the width of the outer div.

Here is a [image: screenschot]

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly there is no css solution for this as it relates to the elements behaviour.
As such I will direct you to another source.
http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/
This changes the width of the element when it is focused on and sets it back when it loses focus. Not very elegant but still allows the whole option to be seen.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That was 50/50 between you and @Tom.

Comment: Dennis, is for a bet, would you've answered without a bounty to this question?

Comment: I would have because it's something I've encountered at work and never had a satisfying answer to.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the div's style and `width: auto; float: right;` to the `<select>` seems to work for me.

```
<div style='width:30px;border:solid 1px; overflow: hidden'>
   <select style='width:auto; float: right;'>
      <option>This is my first option</option>
      <option>option</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

See working example at http://jsfiddle.net/J7sYq/10/

Comment: That was 50/50 between you and @Dennis.

Comment: This worked for me: added `overflow:hidden` to the container, then `width:auto;float:right` to CSS `select:focus`.

Answer (score 1):

I know there are already a whole bunch of answers here. But none of the workarounds really suits my requirement when I met the same problem: I need to put the select inside a fixed width div. Beyond the width, it will be hidden and I don't want to see this - it's pure ugly. The first time I saw [this](http://css-tricks.com/select-cuts-off-options-in-ie-fix/) link, I though I finally found what I want. But after playing with the demo, I was disappointed. The CSS tricks works a bit but it will change the width in whole not just the drop down list. What I need is a really nice looking select just as it should look on other browsers than IE.

I finally worked it out myself using javascript and css plus some ie version specific check. This is a summary of what I did:

1. Use a transparent div the same size as the select to cover the select. Now we can still see the item under the div but we cannot click on it.
2. The transparent div now intercept the mouse click and populate an unordered list with the items from the select. Then we show the list right under the original select. It looks exactly like a clicked select on other browsers.
3. When an item is selected in the unordered list, the list will be hidden and the corresponding item in the original select will be selected.

This approach requires more code, but it really simulate the "right" behavior of the select. The unordered list is styled with css, making it easier to change the look. It is tested under ie7-8.

Following is a screenshot from a working project viewed in ie 8:

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any solution (this is IE fancy world). Maybe a different widget for IE8 or less (extjs combo, jquery ui combo or some pop menu library).

Answer (score -1):

This is what works for me:

```
<div style='max-width:300px;min-width:300px;border:solid 1px'>
<select style='width:300px'>
<option>This is my first option</option>
<option>option</option>
</select>
</div>
<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score -2):

use `*` before your css property for ie specific css.
When marked with `*` only ie8 can understand

```
p.myclass {
     width: 30px;
     *width: 300px;
}/* Just an example*/
```

The ie8 browser will take its own property what you specify and use that. By this you can alert your site specific to ie8, but your property with * should come after the default property. see the code

Answer (score -2):

You have specified width to the outer div consisting the select box. And it looks the same for me in all browsers.

If you want it to stretch based on the length of the options in the select box, then simply just don't specify any width or just say width:auto.
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/J7sYq/3/

Comment: this what the markup is in your jsfiddle. Note: check the width:30px specified <div style='width:30px;border:solid 1px'>
<select style='width:100%'>
<option>This is my first option</option> 
<option>option</option>
</select>
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div style='width:300px;border:solid 1px'>
<select style='width:100%'>
<option>This is my first option</option>
<option>option</option>
</select>
</div>

Comment: what do you want to tell me, sorry I don't understand.

Comment: click in the first combo in IE8, click in the combo in FF or chrome and you'll see the difference

Comment: I am sorry, i don't understand what your problem is. It appears the same for me in all browsers. Can you post screen-shots ?

Comment: Did you test in IE8 (not IE9 with compatibility) ?

Comment: It's easy, IE8 is the only one where the options are cut to the size of the select box (you'll only see a couple of characters). For all others the options are larget than the 30px, so fully visible.

Comment: I didn't check in standalone IE8.