# Internet explorer Select-form width problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

I am using simple HTML code to display a select dropdown box. It works properly in Google Chrome, Firefox etc. but it didnt work as I want it to be in Internet explorer. The select dropdown became too long that it was been out in the box in IE.

I already tried to specify the width: 100%;  and max-width: 100% of the select class but it didn't help.

[image]

```css
.form-parent {
    .form-container {
        input {
            border-color: $ThemeColorLightGray;
            background-color: $ThemeColorLightGray;
        }
    }
}

.form-container {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 40px;

    .form-control,
    .base-datepicker[readonly] {
        border-color: $ThemeColorLightGray;
        background-color: $ThemeColorLightGray;
    }
    .form-tooltip {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        }
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0;
}

select {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: start;
  white-space: pre;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  cursor: default;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="" class="custom-form form-parent js-flex-box">
  <div class="form-container">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="groupOrder" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: red;">
          <select name="Hotel" placeholder="Vælg hotel" title="Vælg hotel" aria-label="Vælg hotel" class="pham form-control pristine touched" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" style="overflow: hidden !important; float: right;">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Vælg hotel</option>
            <option value="Wakeup Copenhagen">Wakeup Copenhagen, Bernstorffsgade</option>
            <option value="Wakeup Copenhagen, Borgergade">Wakeup Copenhagen, Borgergade</option>
            <option value="Wakeup Copenhagen, Carsten Niebuhrs Gade">Wakeup Copenhagen, Carsten Niebuhrs Gade</option>
            <option value="Wakeup Aarhus, Bruunsgade">Wakeup Aarhus, Bruunsgade</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-tooltip">
          <div style="display: none;">Dette felt skal udfyldes</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try the accepted answer in this similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801021/width-issues-using-html-select-within-a-div-using-ie

Comment: Also, how can we possibly help without a single shred of code? For all we know you might have a class that says `width:20000px`.

Comment: @ThomasByy I tried to attach the code now please check

Comment: You have called `100%` width on the select box in 3 different locations. Can you post the image of what it looks like on Chrome. Maybe the padding is causing it to be > 100%;

Comment: @ThomasByy I have online link if you want to visit if its ok with you

Comment: @ThomasByy I attached the Google image at the end of the code. Please Check

Comment: @Pham, You also need to post the code for form-group class and other related parent classes. Otherwise your above code is giving the similar output in Chrome, IE and other browsers. See here. https://i.postimg.cc/zXWrG5yS/176.png It can help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  thanks for the advice. I posted the new code and image hope you have time to look on it.

Comment: @pham, still there is no css code for some classes and I got the same result as before. Please see the new testing result here. https://i.postimg.cc/pTyvyYzg/178.png

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  heres my online site https://www.wakeupcopenhagen.com/prices/group-bookings#/  the problem was in Select Hotel dropdown can you still guide me which code is missing when you visit the site ?

Comment: I check your site with IE 11 and it looks fine with it. Please see here. https://i.postimg.cc/Z5ppD2s5/54.gif Can you please inform us which IE version you are using to making this test? If you are using any older version than make a test with IE 11 may help to fix the issue.

Comment: Im using IE 11 also, the problem occurs when you click other form or outside the select hotel dropdown ex.  2-3 times, when you try to go back in Select Hotel  dropdown the box width become too wide same as the picture above.

Comment: I again try to follow your above steps and try to click on other forms and also try to click on outside for many times and than try to select the drop down but still it looks fine on my side. Still issue is not producible with IE 11.

Comment: super I will try to test other computer with IE 11 installed. Thanks a lot @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: Did you tested on other machines? What output you got? Let us know about your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap this under one more main container as i did and it worked

main changes

wrap in main container

```
    <div class='mainCon' style='background-color: red;width: 80%;'> 
     ........
     ........
     ........
    </div>
```

and then in css

```
#mainCon
{
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.pham {
    width: 100%;
}

#mainCon
{
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(2.25rem + 2px);
    padding: .375rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ced4da;
    border-radius: 0;
    }
   
   select {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: black;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: start;
    white-space: pre;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: default;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class='mainCon' style='background-color: red;width: 80%;'>

<div class="form-group">


  <div>
  <input type='text'>
  </div>

<div>
  <input type='text'>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type='text'>
  </div>
<select name="Hotel" placeholder="Vælg hotel" title="Vælg hotel" aria-label="Vælg hotel" class="pham form-control pristine touched" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Vælg hotel</option>
    <option value="Sample1">Sample 1</option>
    <option value="Sample2">Sample 2</option>
    <option value="Sample3">Sample 3</option>
    <option value="Sample4">Sample 4</option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-tooltip">
    <div style="display: none;">Dette felt skal udfyldes</div>
  </div>
</div>

 <div>
  <input type='text'>
  </div>

<div>
  <input type='text'>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type='text'>
  </div>

</div>
```